# HTTP redirects showing ip address

Tags: http, redirect, dns, frame, frameset

I have a domain name on 1&1 and a VPS on Linode. I noticed that my site was enclosed in a frameset which I didn't create. I checked nginx and jetty in the VPS but none of them created the frameset. Then I checked the domain control panel in 1&1 and saw that the redirection could be a frame redirect or an http redirect. I changed to http redirect and the frameset was gone, everything was fine except for the fact that in the url bar of the browser it changed to the ip address of the server instead of my domain url. How can I avoid the frameset and still have the proper url displayed instead of an IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked it in ServerFault and the answer was to point the domain's A record at my VPS.